# Is this the correct thought process to show that this set is both open and closed?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a set and $(M, d)$ be a metric space. By $M^X$ we denote the set of functions $X \to M$. Define $d_\infty : M^X × M^X \to R$ by $$d_\infty(f, g) = \sup_{x \in X} d(f(x), g(x)).$$
Recall that $f : X \to M$ is bounded if $f(X) \subset  B_r(a) := \{m ∈ M |d(m, a) < r\}$ for some $r \in R$ and $a \in M$.

Show that the set $B(X, M) = \{f : X \to M| f \text{ is bounded}\} \subset M^X$
is closed and open.

What I'm thinking so far is: to prove it's open, we use the fact that f is bounded which implies that $f(x) \subset B(a)<r$, so $f(x)<r$ and so is open as it doesn't include its endpoints. To show it's closed, I think we could do this by again noting that f is bounded and so it contains all of its limit points. Am I thinking about this the correct way? Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: for some reason it wont let me add any more text to my question. the rest of my argument was going to go like : because f(x) ⊂ B(a)<r , then f(x)<r and so the set is open because it doesn't include its endpoints. to show its closed I was thinking that because f is bounded that it contains all of its limit points. Am I thinking about this in the correct way ? any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I have seen longer messages appearing.

Comment: d_oo is not a metric.  It is an extended metric witn values in R^+, the extended reals.  Your definition of bounded with r in R^+ seems wrong if R^+ is the extended reals.

Comment: So have I. I don't know why it cut me short. I tried going back and editing it but no luck, it still wont let me.

Comment: @WilliamElliot but doesn't the set B(X,M) only include bounded functions ?

Comment: The problem was that you used a `<` outside a maths or code environment. Thus the parser interpreted it as the start of an (invalid) HTML tag, not as text to be displayed. I've converted the mathematical statements into MathJax markup to get it all displayed.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I don't see what d_oo has to do with the final question about B(X,M) because i thought that d was a different function d:f(x)Xf(y)->R that isn't involved in the functions f:X->M of which B(X,M) are made of ? Am i thinking about this incorrectly >

Comment: @exodius.  So R^+ is the positive reals and not the extended reals.

Comment: @exodius.  The metric is not defined for all the functions.  Are you using an extended metric?  Otherwise what is the space under consideration  for which the set of bounded functions is a subset?